# FFMPEG: Add FrameRate Option Seconds Stream

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to Copy Two H264 stream into One MP4 File. But I want to set the Framerate for Both H264 stream before copying into One MP4 File. I am able to set FrameRate for First Video H264 Stream. But not able to able to set FrameRate for Seconds Video H264 Stream.

Here are my attempts.

```
ffmpeg -r:v:0 15 -i 15FPS.h264 -r:v:1 30 -i 30FPS.h264 -c:v:0 copy -c:v:1 copy -map 0 -map 1 hello.mp4

ffmpeg -r:v:0 15 -i 15FPS.h264 -r:v:1 30 -i 30FPS.h264 -c copy -map 0 -map 1 hello.mp4
```

First H264 Stream in MP4 File is with 15 FPS but For Second Stream FFMPEG takes by default FPS setting with 25 even I specified 30 explicitly.

Can Someone Point me which part is wrong in my command. It would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2nd stream specifier is wrong. It should also be `-r:v:0` since `-r` is a per-file option and raw .h264 can contain only one stream. (So you can drop the specifier altogether)

```
ffmpeg -r 15 -i 15FPS.h264 -r 30 -i 30FPS.h264 -c copy -map 0 -map 1 hello.mp4
```

Comment: Appreciated your help. Thanks. I didn't know about Pre-file option and all.